# Undivided highways?

Tags: word-meaning

> The maximum speed limit on most California highways is 65 mph. You may drive 70 mph where posted. Unless otherwise posted, the maximum speed limit is 55 mph on two-lane **undivided** highways and for vehicles towing trailers.

When they say undivided , do they mean a highway in which traffic go in one direction?

Comment: This refers to highways where the two directions are not separated by a divider/median. [This](http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/blogs/themoment/posts/111708highway.jpg) is a divided highway, [these](http://www.wsdot.wa.gov/NR/rdonlyres/2CF09029-675C-4BB1-B48C-80E5EBA7E16D/0/CLRS.jpg) are undivided. You can see why the limit is lower on undivided highways; you're driving right past cars going in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 4):

No, they mean a 'standard' road with one lane going one way, and another going the other way. Undivided means, in this case, that there is nothing separating the two lanes (ie a barrier or median strip).

Answer (score 4):

A divided highway is one where the lanes going in opposite directions are divided by a barrier of some sort -- usually a concrete barrier or a grass divide.

An undivided highway has nothing physically separating you from the oncoming traffic.

Answer (score 1):

"Undivided" by the central reservation.